# Spring Security redirects to microservice directly

Tags: java, ssl, spring-security, netflix-zuul

I have a zuul API gateway, which is secured with ssl (https) on port 8443.
I also have two microservices. One of them is a simple REST endpoint,
and the other one is a microservice, which is secured with Spring Security.

The problem is that spring security is not using the gateway. If I go to the following URL, then it stays on that URL and everything is fine:

> https://localhost:8443/restendpoint

However, when I access the following URL, it doesn't stay on the same URL:

> https://localhost:8443/auth

Rather than staying on the same URL, it doesn't stay on the gateway and goes to the following URL:

> http://localhost:9000/auth

However, I need it to stay on the gateway because the auth service is not secured with ssl.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow your description.  Explain the architecture a little more in depth.  Include which services have Spring Security as a dependency.  An example repo on GitHub would be easiest.

Comment: Basicly only the auth Service has Spring Security as a dependency. And because of this it does not let me stay on the gateway. It makes the user access the microservice directly.

Comment: There must be a redirect being issued by the auth service, and it includes the Location as itself (e.g. port 9000) since it doesn't know about the gateway.  Can you examine the HTTP request/responses to confirm?  A minimal sample app that reproduces the issue would be helpful.

Comment: Here is a sample app which reproduces the redirect.
Thank you for your help.
https://github.com/bredx27/zuul-sample/

Comment: Check this [Pull Request](https://github.com/bredx27/zuul-sample/pull/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Hey, I just found out, that it won´t work when I am using port 8443.
Any other port works. Is it because of ssl? How can I solve this?